# transforming input string into an integer

Tags: string, integer

for the below code, when I run it, and input a float as the capacity_engine input, I get an error msg: invalid literal for int base 10. Can someone explain why and the fix?

```
fuel_type = input("Please enter your fuel type, P for Petrol and D for Diesel: ")
capacity_engine = int(input("What is the capacity of your engine?: "))
distance_travelled = int(input("Please enter distance travelled in your car in km: "))

if fuel_type == "P":
    if capacity_engine <= 2:
        print("Your emission value per tonne is 0.208")
    else:
        print("Your emission value per tonne is 0.176")
elif fuel_type == "D":
    if capacity_engine <= 2:
        print("Your emission value per tonne is 0.296")
    else:
        print("Your emission value per tonne is 0.236")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your question yourself. You're inputting a float, but trying to convert it to int on line 2.

The fix should be changing int(...) to float(...) on line 2.